# Failed to load in else condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to embedd video to my loop with condition. I try this code:

```
 <?php if (function_exists("wp_oembed_get")) {
 $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wiki_test_embed', 1 ) );
 echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
 } else{    ?>
    No Video Here
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Everything work fine when videpinserted to the post, but when the post have no video, the text "No Video Here" doesnt appear.

Really appreciate for any helps.

Comment: You probably also want a `if($url)` in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is checking whether the function, `wp_oembed_get()`, exists. That should be true regardless of whether your post contains a video or not. You'll never hit the else statement.

Instead of checking for the existence of a function, you need to be evaluating the value of your meta field. Example:

```
if ( $video_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wiki_test_embed', true ) ) {
    echo wp_oembed_get( esc_url( $video_url ) );
} else {
    echo 'No video was found.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the <?php tag in a way that you are cutting the if else condition. Try this.

```html
 <?php 
 
 if(function_exists("wp_oembed_get")) {
    $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wiki_test_embed', 1 ) );
    echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
 } else{   
    echo( 'No Video Here' );
 }
 
 ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately it's similar with my code, didn't work. Thank you anyway.